# Upgrade from 21.04 to 21.10 is stuck at "setting up redis-server"

Tags: do-release-upgrade, 21.10

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10. The upgrade has been stuck for more than 2 hours at "Setting up redis-server".

I am worried about cancelling the upgrade because it might break something.

Here is a screenshot of where the upgrade is stuck:

[image: screenshot of "Distribution Upgrade" window with terminal]

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another window that asks you for information?

Comment: Release upgrades are not always successful.  If the process has been stuck for more than two hours, you will probably need to cancel it.  If that happens you have a few options:  If nothing is "broken" you can try again.  If there are problems, you can provide details about those problems and we can try to collaborate to fix them. But the best path might end up being a clean installation of 21.10 -- that should take significantly less than 2 hours, which you've already spent

Comment: Yes there are no other terminals open @Jos

Comment: Will do that. Thanks @Nmath

Comment: I canceled the update and after I rebooted it, the dual boot options came. I booted to windows and it worked fine but when I tried to boot to ubuntu. It freezes on the lenovo screen. After some research i came to know that I can boot from another versions in advanced ubuntu options. I booted from ubuntu with linux 5.11.0-41 generic and everything works normally. How can I set this version to default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck as well, for me just manually stopping the service by running

```
sudo service redis-server stop
```

allowed to continue with upgrade instantly.

Comment: Saved my day, when upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04. Sad there is no message requesting the service to be stopped.